# How to make logs globalization for django app?

Tags: django, globalization

In django's globalization utility https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/, we can translate the messages based on request's locale and return the translated messages back to clients.

But consider logging case, which require to translate the messages based on current runtime environment, as commmon python code do "logger.info(_(msg))". Seems there will be conflict here.

For my scenario, assume django app running on an EN locale, but get the the requests from DE. Then I hope the response can be Germeny, but the logs kept at English. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://www.janosgyerik.com/detect-language-preference-in-django-and-confirm-it-works/?